# Can we modify boss thread count

Tags: netty, reactor-netty

I would like to modify event loop group with my own thread count for boss and worker event loop groups. Unfortunately reactor-netty seems to have modified a lot. The doc no longer provides what is what!!

I am not really sure how to customize!! Looks like Loop Resources is an option. But i do not see boss thread configuration.

If you are familiar with reactor-netty, can you explain what is LoopResources. I did check [here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/api/reactor/netty/resources/LoopResources.html). It is not clear. Thats why I ask this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you need to configure the **boss** event loop group you can do the following (the configuration below is just an example, you can specify your own `select` and `worker` count, name etc.):

```
LoopResources loop = LoopResources.create("my-elg", 1, 10, true);
HttpServer.create()
          .runOn(loop);
```

```
static LoopResources create(String prefix,
                            int selectCount,
                            int workerCount,
                            boolean daemon)
Create a simple LoopResources to provide automatically for EventLoopGroup and Channel factories
Parameters:
prefix - the event loop thread name prefix
selectCount - number of selector threads
workerCount - number of worker threads
daemon - should the thread be released on jvm shutdown
Returns:
a new LoopResources to provide automatically for EventLoopGroup and Channel factories
```

Where `selectCount` is the **boss** count.

https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/api/reactor/netty/resources/LoopResources.html#create-java.lang.String-int-int-boolean-

Also see the [Reference Documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#server-tcp-level-configurations-event-loop-group)